# What is the efficiency of memorizing pieces of text? How much time does such activity have to take?

Tags: memorization

It is common task to memorize word by word lines from verses and prose for toddlers, schoolchildren and even students for their L1 and foreign language.

I've noticed that such activity put lots of pressure on a student and we had extremely small amount of such assignments in comparison to other activities (solving tasks, writing essays, analyzing grammar).

Is there some scientific ground for text memorizing assignments?

Is it only for children? How about adults?

Does it help with a language acquisition or just makes memory stronger?

Answer (score 1):

I collected some evidence and notes for my question:

- memorizing useless pieces is useless, like:

  - famous speeches "I have a dream" - not useful vocabulary
  - chapters of Shakespeare ("Be or not to be") - outdated vocabulary
  - simple grammar (This is a table / This is an apple) - same rule applied infinitely
- Paul Nation recommends (from [What do you need to know to learn a foreign language - 2014](https://www.wgtn.ac.nz/lals/resources/paul-nations-resources/paul-nations-publications/publications/documents/foreign-language_1125.pdf)):

> The quickest way to begin speaking in another language is to memorize useful phrases and  sentences.  The  very  first  phrases  and  sentences  should  come  from  the  **survival  vocabulary** which includes greetings, expressions of politeness, the language needed for shopping and moving around, numbers, the language needed in a restaurant, and brief  descriptions  of  yourself,  your  work,  and  your  reasons  for  being  in  the  foreign  country.

> Activity 4.1: Memorized sentences and dialogues.
>
> Write the sentences you want to memorize on small cards with their first language translation on the back. Ideally, you should get some help with pronunciation of these phrases and sentences before working on memorizing them.When  memorizing,  look  at  the  first  language  translation  and  try  to  recall  the  foreign  language  phrase or sentence.
>
> The phrases and sentences should be ones that **you can use immediately**.
>
> Deliberate memorization is fast and long-lasting and makes material readily available for language use.

Comment: The quotes assume the language is being learned as a tourist or to live one's life. Being explicit about the assumption would improve the answer.

Comment: It is the problem of Paul's article (( I haven't stated anything about survival vocabulary in the question. It is still interesting to know evidence for memorization if you are at B2-C2 level.